# what are properties of 1 divide by root of unity?

Tags: complex-numbers

so recently I have encountered a problem that require me to do a step which is to use one to divide by root of unity of $2^n-1$. I was wondering is there any special property of $1/w$ where w is the root of unity?( I tested on root of unity of 3 and it turns out that when $1/w$ the result is another root of untiy)

Comment: Well that is really useful! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$\omega^k=1\iff\frac{\omega^k}{\omega^k}=\frac1{\omega^k}\iff1=\frac1{\omega^k}$$So it is still a root of unity, just a different one.  Particularly, if $\omega_a$ is the $a$th root of unity, then $\frac1{\omega_a}$ is the $(k-a)$th root of unity by Euler's formula.